# Relationship between HttpContext & HttpConnection

Tags: http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

Does a HttpContext always have only one HttpConnection? When I execute a request, does it maintain only one HttpConnection even though there may be multiple socket connections due to redirects etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpContext` always refers to the current or the last connection used by the HTTP exchange regardless of how many intermediate connection may have been employed in the course of the exchange. Connection re-use and pooling is a responsibility of the connection manager.

Comment: Are multiple `HttpConnenction` instances created and destroyed in the same `HttpContext` while executing a request redirected to different domains or is just the socket connection swapped out in the same `HttpConnection` instance?

Comment: HttpConnenction instances stored in the context are actually dynamic proxies. Those proxies may stay in the context but the underlying connection gets released back to the manager immediately after the response has been fully consumed. Connection proxies are disposable and are never re-used.